# Select Count (case when)!

Tags: sql-server

Friends, I would like help from you to find a solution to the following case:

A table with 2 fields: datetime, record (the record being any number that can be repeated a few times)

I need to count how many times each record appears in 12h, 24h, and 72h intervals.

Example, supposing record number 1: It appears 2 times in a 12h interval, plus 1 within 24h and another 3 in the 72h interval.

Thus, for the first record 1, in the 12-hour column there would be a value of 2, a 24-hour value would be 3, a 72-hour value would be 6. In the second row of record 1 the results would be: for 12h value 1, 24h value 2, 72h value 5 and so on.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How do you come up with "the second row of record 1"? Just do not get you. Better, write a table and populate it with some values so we can understand you.

Comment: throw sample data

Comment: Define interval. 12 horus from each other or from the current date time? If it's the first, then is this dynamic across each record meaning a 12hr window for one record isn't the same for another?

Comment: DATE;REGISTRO;2H;6H;12H;24H
27/03/2018 00:00:02;A;0;1;1;1
27/03/2018 00:14:26;B;0;1;1;1
27/03/2018 02:24:02;A;1;1;1;1
27/03/2018 02:52:50;A;1;1;1;1
27/03/2018 04:19:14;A;0;1;1;1
27/03/2018 04:48:02;B;0;1;1;1
27/03/2018 06:43:14;A;1;1;1;1
27/03/2018 07:40:50;B;1;1;1;1
27/03/2018 08:09:38;B;0;1;1;1
27/03/2018 08:38:26;A;0;1;1;1
27/03/2018 10:33:38;B;1;1;1;1
27/03/2018 11:16:50;A;0;0;1;1
27/03/2018 11:45:38;B;1;1;1;1
27/03/2018 12:57:38;B;1;1;1;1
27/03/2018 14:24:02;B;1;1;1;1
27/03/2018 14:38:26;B;1;1;1;1
27/03/2018 16:19:14;B;0;0;0;0
27/03/2018 18:00:02;A;0;0;0;0

Comment: The calculation needs to iterate between all the records in the table to check not only the record but also the time interval of that time + 2h forwards or + 6h, + 12h, + 24h or + 72h

Answer (score 1):

I can share the conceptual answer to this problem, you will have to fill in correct syntax for query as per your database engine.

```
select record, count(record)
from table
where datetime is interval of 12 hours from now
group by record
```

This query can give you record occurrences in one single interval of time.

```
select record, 
   SUM(case when datetime is in interval 12h then 1 else 0 end) 12_hour_occurrence,
   SUM(case when datetime is in interval 24h then 1 else 0 end) 24_hour_occurrence,
   SUM(case when datetime is in interval 72h then 1 else 0 end) 72_hour_occurrence
from table
where datetime > now() - 72 hours # don't pass thorugh extra records
group by record
```

For running on single query on multiple instances, you can use this concept to find occurrences in multiple intervals.

Comment: Hassan, thank you for the help. The way is almost this, but it's not exactly that. I could not explain correctly what I need. This calculation needs to check in the time column all intervals for each record. It is not -72h from now, but + 72h from the time of registration in the table.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoNogueiraGondim - do you mean interval since the first time any record appeared in the table? If yes, then `now()` can be replace with `min()` datetime for each record and `-` with `+`.

It will be helpful to see actual data for example records: {1, 2, 3} you have shared in the problem statement.

Comment: see this exemple: DATE;REGISTRO;2H;6H;12H;24H 27/03/2018 00:00:02;A;0;1;1;1 27/03/2018 00:14:26;B;0;1;1;1 27/03/2018 02:24:02;A;1;1;1;1 27/03/2018 02:52:50;A;1;1;1;1 27/03/2018 04:19:14;A;0;1;1;1 27/03/2018 04:48:02;B;0;1;1;1 27/03/2018 06:43:14;A;1;1;1;1 27/03/2018 07:40:50;B;1;1;1;1 27/03/2018 08:09:38;B;0;1;1;1 27/03/2018 08:38:26;A;0;1;1;1 27/03/2018 10:33:38;B;1;1;1;1 27/03/2018 11:16:50;A;0;0;1;1 27/03/2018 11:45:38;B;1;1;1;1 27/03/2018 12:57:38;B;1;1;1;1 27/03/2018 14:24:02;B;1;1;1;1 27/03/2018 14:38:26;B;1;1;1;1 27/03/2018 16:19:14;B;0;0;0;0 27/03/2018 18:00:02;A;0;0;0;

Comment: I'm using sql server, not MySql.